# Setting a properties file in Spring Batch via a JobParameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have three different .properties files in a Spring Batch project, and I'm trying to set which .properties file should be used as a JobParameter. I'd like to be able to run the job like so:

```
java CommandLineJobRunner context.xml jobName region=us
```

The region should specify which .properties file should be used. The problem is getting the context to recognize the JobParameter. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.#{jobParameters['region']}.properties"/>
```

And also:

```
<util:properties id="batchProperties" location="classpath:batch.#{jobParameters['region']}.properties"></util:properties>
```

I had heard that adding scope="step" could fix similar issues, but I tried adding that to both of the above solutions and still had exceptions.

I think I'm missing a fundamental idea of why I can't get this working, but I'm unable to figure out what that idea is.

If anyone has any suggestions on getting this working and/or explaining why my previous approaches failed, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the right way to proceed (it is impossible do what you are trying to do).
You have to think that `jobParameters` is available only when a job is running and only for its composing steps marked with `scope="step"` (and not `<context:property-placeholder>` nor `<util:properties>` has a `step` attribute).
A way for solving the problem is to load properties file in job's execution context before first step is running with a listener:

```
public class PropertyLoaderJobExecutionListener extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {
  Properties countryProperties;

  public void setCountryProperties(Properties pfb) {
    this.countryProperties = pfb;
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    super.beforeStep(stepExecution);
    // Store property file content in jobExecutionContext with name "batchProperties"
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("batchProperties", countryProperties);
  }
}
```

in your job.xml

```
<bean id="loadPropertiesListener" class="PropertyLoaderJobExecutionListener" scope="step">
  <property name="pfb">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
      <property name="location" value="classpath:batch.#{jobParameters['region']}.properties" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and register this listener in your first step (you can't do that in your `JobExectionListsner.beforeJob()` because there isn't a `scope="job"` for now and late-binding of `#{jobParameters['region']}` value is not available).

To access your data with spEL use this syntax:

```
#{jobExecutionContext.get('batchProperties').getProperty('language')}
```

or a better syntax to access properties (IDK spEL so good, sorry).

Hope to be clear and can help to solve your problem.

EDIT (full code of my working job.xml):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    <job id="sourceJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="step1">
            <tasklet ref="getRemoteFileTasklet" />
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="loadPropertiesListener" />
            </listeners>
        </step>
    </job>
    <bean id="loadPropertiesListener" class="PropertyLoaderJobExecutionListener" scope="step">
        <property name="pfb">
            <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
                <property name="location" value="classpath:batch.#{jobParameters['region']}.properties" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="getRemoteFileTasklet" class="GetRemoteFileTasklet" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I've implemented your suggestion, but I'm getting an error when trying to load batchProperties:

EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'batchProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'

I have never used spEL before, so I'm not 100% sure what is happening. It looks like the Listener is not being called, even though I have it defined in the job now. I defined the listener inside the <Job> tag but before any <Steps>. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: I also tried putting it in the Step but below the Tasklet and the Listener is still not executing.

Comment: you can't use as job listener (as described in my answer), but as step listener. Put as listener in first step of your job. Put a breakpoint in PropertyLoaderJobExecutionListener to see if listener is called. spring-batch at 2.2.1 version (I have tried on my PC and it works)

Comment: I've tried putting it in the first step, but the same thing happens. Never hits the break point. Here's the code:

<step id="getRemoteFileStep" next="preprocessingStep">
   <tasklet ref="getRemoteFileTasklet" />
   <listeners>
          <listener ref="loadPropertiesListener"/>
         </listeners>
  </step>

Comment: edit my answer with full - working and tested - code (except for a second step); are you sure your job is not restarting from step2? (try -restart in commandline). Are you using latest version of batch framework?

Comment: Thanks for posting the full code, and sorry for the long pause between replies. I had a syntax issue which was causing my last problem, but now I'm getting an error stating "Field or property 'jobExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'". I'm hoping it's something silly that I missed, so I'm going to keep hunting and trying to figure this out, but if you have any ideas I'm open to hearing them. Thanks.

Comment: Missing `scope="step"` usually

Comment: Thanks! I had to add scope="step" to all beans that use properties. I'm getting a new error now, will update after trying to figure it out.

Comment: That did the trick! Had a small syntax error which was throwing the whole thing off. Thanks a lot for all the help!