# can i launch a Spring Batch application with a dynamic property file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

In Spring Batch am I able to invoke a launch context as such:

```
-classpath -Dprops.file=file:C:/log-inspector-batch/log-inspector-batch/config/daily_report-log.properties %OP% org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner launch-context.xml log_inspector_batch_simple
```

to goal here is to inject the property file which is responsible for the configuration of some scanning logs logic that the application performs. Problem is we don't wish to edit any code to add a new scan location, i just wish to add launch the application context by injecting a dynamic property file. Is this possible???

The end result would be many batches for example 50 of them, scanning different log locations based on the property file (trying to find a way how to know which property file to use on invocation). In my launch-context.xml I have:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${props.file}" />
```

the error i am getting is that it can't find the property file i am injecting:

```
ERROR CommandLineJobRunner:368 - Job Terminated in error: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${props.file}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: please share the complete start script including "java ...." because it works for me, maybe its a problem with order of params

Comment: i found this thread that does it differently:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516012/setting-a-properties-file-in-spring-batch-via-a-jobparameter

runs the property file as job params